# JSON - string value conversion to List

Tags: python, json

Code used for extraction from JSON

```
import json
string = json.loads(data)
string['Body']

import base64
base64.b64decode(string['Body'])

bytes_data = base64.b64decode(string['Body'])
str(bytes_data, encoding='utf-8')
```

I have a following format that is extracted from JSON

```
"[{"id":"XXXX_U2_170216:XXXX_U2_170216:FBE_23015.Air","values":[{"v":"46","q":192,"t":"2021-10-28T13:47:59.7880096Z"}]},
{"id":"XXXX_U2_170216:XXXX_U2_170216:FBE_23015.Atomise","values":[{"v":"3.1","q":192,"t":"2021-10-28T13:47:59.7880096Z"}]}]"
```

Any idea about converting it to actual list

```
[{"id":"XXXX_U2_170216:XXXX_U2_170216:FBE_23015.Air","values":[{"v":"46","q":192,"t":"2021-10-28T13:47:59.7880096Z"}]},
{"id":"XXXX_U2_170216:XXXX_U2_170216:FBE_23015.Atomise","values":[{"v":"3.1","q":192,"t":"2021-10-28T13:47:59.7880096Z"}]}]
```

things I have tried :

```
list(bytearray(bytes_data))
```

for loop - for this output string, but this is a convoluted way to do it.
some more conversion stuff. looking for something that is compact.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. What is `data`? I see no base64 encoded values, so why are you decoding? Where is `Body` key in your data?

Comment: The data is decoded part. I dont have problem there. Body is what I am getting in a string format, I am trying to convert to a list. Better if that can be converted to dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the built-in [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module:

```
import json
data = json.loads(bytes_data)
```

It seems like you have a json inside  a json, so load it twice:

```
import json
import base64

string = json.loads(data)
bytes_data = base64.b64decode(string['Body'])
output = json.loads(bytes_data)
```

Comment: OP already knows about `json.loads`. Where are you getting `string['Body']` from the data shown?

Comment: @OneCricketeer as far as I understand, he extracted the `Body` field from the json, and he showed you the output, which is by itself a json.

Comment: Seems like a guess, considering there is no print statement shown, but we'll see.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Not a guess, he showed you the code he's using to extract the json data, and then the data (which is formatted as a json again). He clearly states that.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse engineering your question....

**Given** a JSON file with base64 data

```
$ cat /tmp/data.json
{
  "Body": "W3siaWQiOiJYWFhYX1UyXzE3MDIxNjpYWFhYX1UyXzE3MDIxNjpGQkVfMjMwMTUuQWlyIiwidmFsdWVzIjpbeyJ2IjoiNDYiLCJxIjoxOTIsInQiOiIyMDIxLTEwLTI4VDEzOjQ3OjU5Ljc4ODAwOTZaIn1dfSwKeyJpZCI6IlhYWFhfVTJfMTcwMjE2OlhYWFhfVTJfMTcwMjE2OkZCRV8yMzAxNS5BdG9taXNlIiwidmFsdWVzIjpbeyJ2IjoiMy4xIiwicSI6MTkyLCJ0IjoiMjAyMS0xMC0yOFQxMzo0Nzo1OS43ODgwMDk2WiJ9XX1dCg=="
}
```

**When** read and extracted

```
import json
import base64
with open('/tmp/data.json') as f:
    string = json.load(f)
body = string['Body']
```

**Then** decoded... a list is returned

```
import pprint

l = json.loads(base64.b64decode(body)
pprint.pprint(l)
```

```
[{'id': 'XXXX_U2_170216:XXXX_U2_170216:FBE_23015.Air',
  'values': [{'v': '46', 'q': 192, 't': '2021-10-28T13:47:59.7880096Z'}]},
 {'id': 'XXXX_U2_170216:XXXX_U2_170216:FBE_23015.Atomise',
  'values': [{'v': '3.1', 'q': 192, 't': '2021-10-28T13:47:59.7880096Z'}]}]
```

Comment: I'm confused, this is the exact same answer I wrote.

Comment: Bharel, apologies. I had skipped that part. 
Idk if there is way to take two answers. I was interacting with @OneCricketeer. I appreciate help from both of you.

Answer (score 0):

use json load method like this, suppose you have JSON array and want to convert in LIST then do following

```
import json
array = '{"Items": ["IPhone", "Earphone", "Powerbackup"]}'
data  = json.loads(array)
print (data['Items'])
```